# Prevent radio button from displaying True or False

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, radio-button, migration

I'm trying to display male or female when a user selects the radio button. However, its displaying true or false. How can I get it to display male or female on my user show page and not true or false. Thank you

**Registration/Edit**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.radio_button :isfemale, true %> <%= f.label :isfemale, "Female" %> 
      <%= f.radio_button :isfemale, false %> <%= f.label :isfemale, "Male" %> 
      </div>
```

**Users/show**

```
<p>
   <b>Gender:</b>
   <%= @user.isfemale %>
</p>
```

**Migration**

```
class AddIsfemaleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :isfemale, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Comment: see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

Comment: Let me know, if you dont understand above link than i can write the answer for you.

Comment: @Murtza Thanks! How would I incorporate that into what I currently have? I am pretty new to Rails. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You are most welcome.. i have added the code for sake of documentation. You can tick the green button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition like this to display what you needed

```
<p>
   <b>Gender:</b>
   <% if @user.isfemale == true %>
   Female
   <% else %>
   Male
   <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan. Unfortunately, I tried that earlier and I get a Syntax Error in my UsersController#show where it says render actions: :show

@posts = user.posts.all
    render actions: :show
   else
    render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
 end

Comment: @Dena I have edited my answer to provide another option which would help for sure.

Comment: @Dena Edited now.Sorry i didn't noticed that i missed an `<% end %>`

Comment: So I tried both ways. The first option gave me 'NameError in Users#show.uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Female

The 2nd option took the labels away on my devise form and the true or false was still displaying. 

I'm trying to play around with it because I'm sure I've missed something small. Unfortunately I am still lost. @Pavan

Comment: @ Pavan Line 4. <%= Female %>

Comment: @Dena Something is wrong.Unfortunately i can't test it now.Will update my answer tomorrow as soon as possible.

Comment: @dena Have you tried my updated answer? Is it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender, "male", :checked => true %>
<%= label :gender_male, :gender, "Male" %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, "female" %>
<%= label :gender_female, :gender, "Female" %>
```